# About the floor function

Tags: calculus, functions

--EDITED--
So I already found that $\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{k}\right\rfloor-2\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor=1$ only when the decimal part of $\frac{n}{k}\in[\frac{1}{2},1)$, yet still I got no idea how to solve this problem......
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{k}\right\rfloor-2\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor\right).$$

Comment: @Gary I see! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Also use ```$\lfloor\rfloor$``` for $\lfloor\rfloor$

Comment: @Gary: Isn't it the Riemann sum for $\int_0^1 \left( \left[ \frac{2}{x}\right] - 2\left[ \frac{1}{x}\right]\right)dx$ rather than $\int_0^1 \left( \left[ 2x\right] - 2\left[ x\right]\right)dx$

Comment: Am I right now?
\begin{aligned}
&{\rm Notice~that}~f(x)=\left\lfloor{2\over x}\right\rfloor-2\left\lfloor{1\over x}\right\rfloor~{\rm is~integrable~on~}[0,1]\\
&\\
&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{k}\right\rfloor-2\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor\right)=\int_0^1f(x){\rm d}x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{1 \over n}^{1\over n-{1\over 2}}f(x){\rm d}x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left({1\over n-{1\over 2}}-{1\over n}\right)\\
&~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left({1\over2n-1}-{1\over2n}\right)=2\ln2
\end{aligned}

Comment: @rryan why not post your answer?

Comment: You can [self answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32384/self-answer-or-delete-my-question)

Comment: Looks like: $\left(\int_0^1 \left(\left\lfloor \frac{2}{x}\right\rfloor -2 \left\lfloor \frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor \right) \, dx=2 \ln (2)-1\right)\approx 0.386294$

Comment: :( Forgot n should start from 2......

Comment: Sorry but I've just started using StackExchange recently so there are many features of this website I haven't explored. I'm trying to keep up.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{aligned}
&{\rm Notice~that}~f(x)=\left\lfloor{2\over x}\right\rfloor-2\left\lfloor{1\over x}\right\rfloor~{\rm is~integrable~on~}[0,1]\\
&\\
&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{k}\right\rfloor-2\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor\right)=\int_0^1f(x){\rm d}x=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\int_{1 \over n}^{1\over n-{1\over 2}}f(x){\rm d}x=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\left({1\over n-{1\over 2}}-{1\over n}\right)\\
&~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~=2\sum_{n=2}^\infty\left({1\over2n-1}-{1\over2n}\right)=2\ln2-1.
\end{aligned}